# How to access parent variables from an embedded page?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a sticky note that appears on and webpage and as I type the contents is stored in the DB along with the URL as a reference

For example, I go to a BBC page, I click cmd+escap and my sticky note appears (it's a **tampermonkey** script)

```
function addEmbed(){ 
    localStorage.setItem("myUniqueAPIcode", window.location);
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.type="text/html"
  iframe.src="http://localhost:8080/webhighlights"
  iframe.style.cssText = `position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  height: 100vh;` 
  return iframe
}
```

That code works, in that the sticky note appears. It is a Vue page. But I can not access the local storage value

```
mounted() {
    if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
      if (localStorage.myUniqueAPIcode) {
        this.api = localStorage.myUniqueAPIcode
      }
    }
       
  },
};
```

I kind of know why, The tampermonkey script is setting the value on the BBC page, and the Vue code is looking in the localhost page.

But, before this, I tried to append the sticky form inside the page themselves but some websites didn't allow to perform fetch requests.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: window.parent.localStorage ??? did you try this or window.top.localStorage

Comment: @robert it throws the error of `SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame`

Comment: iframe.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-scripts allow-same-origin"); or try use postMessage and comunicate with parent frame [Post Messaeg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) [Post Message](https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-pass-data-between-iframe-and-parent-window/)this cross-origin security blockade but for shure at least you shuld read [this](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication)